# PHP Regex - Remove invalid characters from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I know there are many regex questions, but I don't know it well enough, nor could I find an answer explaining it well enough to derive the solution I'm trying to get.

In PHP, using

```
preg_replace($pattern,"",$data);
```

I'd like to allow all alphanumeric characters along with the minus, period, and underscore characters. What is the $pattern I need?

Comment: @SulemanC you used basically the same pattern as me, but you have a `+` in there that does not belong

Comment: A -1 for asking this question? Seriously.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but was tempted to on the basis of showing no research effort. This question is essentially "What is the regex that I need?", where it would've better been approach as "I tried this regex, but it's not matching these input test cases".

Comment: I spent 1-2 hours researching and couldn't find anything helpful. For example, even here, and as much as I appreciate the help, the information gives the answer but no detailed explanation. So there's no way for someone who knows only a little regex could expand from it. I eventually googled "regex negated character class" which eventually lead me to a decent explanation. But if not for that string to google, I wouldn't have a clue how this worked. Most regex answers are like that, answer but no explanation. And as more and more answers appear, it's harder and harder to google :(

Comment: Instead of searching for your exact situation on google/SO it would probably be more helpful to read the PCRE documentation on php.net http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: That's probably not enough. And I don't really need to be an expert at regex. Normally the regex solutions I need are pretty simple and I can just figure them out. I just didnt' know about the negate character as I never needed to filter out data. What you're suggesting is much like someone learn the full Java API before asking anything related to Java. The intent of SO as Jeff has said many times is not to RTFM, but to help people get there. With regex if you don't RTFM in full, well good luck. With regex you can't just grab important parts easily from the docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$pattern = "/[^\w.-]/";
```

This is the negated character class of exactly the requirements you described.

Comment: @The_Land_Of_Devils_SriLanka interesting .. do you have any proof of that?

Comment: it would replace each non word character 1 by 1 instead of replacing it in bulk..i don't have any proof for that but that's the way regex engine would replace..

Comment: @The_Land_Of_Devils_SriLanka well I don't have any proof either, but I think that PHP would compile the expression so that the replacement is optimized

Comment: In a match, the quantifier wouldn't matter, but I agree that adding a quantifier in here should make the replacement faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i know this is not Regex...

*$answer*=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", *$data*);

Answer (score -1):

maybe this can be tried:

```
$cleaner_input = trim(strip_tags($text));
```